# Disable sort pagination in view CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I sort my data in controller:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 40,
    'page' => $this->request->params['page'],
    'group' => 'movie_id',
    'order' => array('start_year' => 'desc', 'votes_count' => 'asc', 'premiere' => 'desc'),
);
```

And when I print pagination in a view I have urls:

```
/pages/newest/page:7/sort:Post.start_year/direction:desc
```

I don't want display this :sort:Post.start_year/direction:desc

In a view:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->first('<< '); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('modulus' => 8)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->last(' >>'); ?>
```

How to disable order in urls in view ?

Comment: Simply by not allowing pagination for those fields. Remove those links from your view.

Answer (score 0):

You should just NOT write anything like that:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('User.name', 'Name');?>
```

In your situation it should be something like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Post.start', 'your column name');?>
```

Comment: But in a view I have only this: <?php echo $this->Paginator->first('<< '); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('modulus' => 8)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->last(' >>'); ?>

Comment: Then how did you end up having a url like that?

Comment: This line: 'order' => array('start_year' => 'desc', 'votes_count' => 'asc', 'premiere' => 'desc'), makes urls like that

Answer (score 0):

Write order statment, without `=>` symbol between field and sorting type, in your case:

```
'order' => array('start_year desc, votes_count asc, premiere desc'),
```

This solve the issue.